# Como evitar que o formulário apague todos os dados após atualizar a página

Tags: html, jquery

Tenho um aplicativo que tem duas telas, **cadastro.html** e **termos.html**. 
No **cadastro.html** tenho um **checkbox** para o usuário aceitar os termos, só consegue se cadastrar se aceitar, mas não é obrigado a abrir a tela de termos.
Mas, caso ele abra, terá lá no final do texto dois botões, **aceitar** e **recusar**.
Digamos que ele aceitou, então volta para página **cadastro.html** com o **checkbox já selecionado,** porém perde todos os dados dos inputs que ele já tinha preenchido.

Minha dúvida é: como faço para não perder esses dados quando ele clicar em **termos.html** e depois redirecionar para **cadastro.html**?

Comment: há algumas possibilidades. 
1 - Você pode salvar os dados em um localStorage e depois recuperá-los.
2  - Abrir o termos em outra aba, utilize (procure por target _blank)
3 - Abrir termos em um modal e desta forma ele não sairia da página.

Comment: Como o Lucas disse, abra o termo em um modal.

Comment: Eu já tinha pensado em um modal, mas queria saber se teria como de outras maneiras.

Comment: Concordo com o que os amigos disseram. Acho que a separação em duas páginas gera um trabalho desnecessário de ter que guardar a informação da aceitação dos termos. Mas a título de informação, utilizando apenas javascript e html, somente com o localStorage ou via parametro de URL você conseguiria esse resultado. Mas nenhum deles eu recomendaria.

Comment: Ou cookie... mas não recomendo

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar `sessionStorage`?

Comment: Possível duplicata de: **1.** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/67219/3635 - **2.** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/424/3635 - **3.** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116395/3635 - **4.** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75557/3635 - **5.** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109935/3635

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer?